# supervisord: dynamically generate config?

Tags: configuration, process, supervisord

Is it possible to dynamically generate the config used by [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)?

I'm working on a project which needs to define all the services in a central location anyway, so it would be very handy if I could somehow trick `supervisord` into using that configuration data as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it, but this Github project claims to do just that:

https://github.com/mnaberez/supervisor_twiddler

Answer (score -1):

Create a new `supervisord.conf` file or add to an existing one, then follow with a `supervisorctl reload` to restart the supervisord process and load the new configuration file, or `supervisorctl reread` if the changes are limited to just some of the processes / groups.